# Reproject coordinates in order to correct them in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I got two type of coordinates(correct values and incorrects(15m error)), and i want to specify transformation parameters between them in QGIS. I thought that finding Helmert transformation parameter values via least squares method, which is supported by QGIS, and add them to proj4 could resolve my problem. 
I wondering if i can use similarity/afine transformation in order to reproject my coordinates? Any suggestion that enable to me correct my coordinates?

---

How can i guess transformation parameters for affine transformation plugin?

Comment: The affine transformation plugin and vector bender plugin should do what you want.

Comment: How do you know which ones are correct. Are the incorrect ones 15 off in a specific direction?

Comment: i check their external accuracy. Actually 15m captures distance difference between the two sets

Comment: For the affine transformation plugin, you have to try out the values yourself. Just enter 10 for the last value in the first line, and see how the offset changes. It should move 10 meters (or degrees) to the East.The last value in the second line will shift up or down.